# error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PREFIX_CONFIG_H

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

This is my whole configure.ac(generated by autoscan),and i add a line `AC_PREIX_CONFIG_H(hotplugin)` in this script:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.63])
AC_INIT([hotplugin], [0.1])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([loader.c])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_CC

# Checks for libraries.
# FIXME: Replace `main' with a function in `-ldl':
AC_CHECK_LIB([dl], [main])
# FIXME: Replace `main' with a function in `-lhotp':
AC_CHECK_LIB([hotp], [main])

# Checks for header files.
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([fcntl.h limits.h stddef.h stdint.h stdlib.h string.h sys/time.h unistd.h])

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
AC_HEADER_STDBOOL
AC_TYPE_OFF_T
AC_TYPE_PID_T
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T
AC_TYPE_SSIZE_T

# Checks for library functions.
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_FUNC_REALLOC
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([memset strchr strdup strerror strstr strtol strtoul])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([makefile])
AC_PREIX_CONFIG_H(hotplugin)
AC_OUTPUT
```

When running `autoconf` in that project, I get the error:

```
configure.ac:35: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PREIX_CONFIG_H
  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
  See the Autoconf documentation.
```

And my tool lists:

```
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.63
autoscan (GNU Autoconf) 2.63
autoheader (GNU Autoconf) 2.63
m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.13
libtoolize (GNU libtool) 2.2.6b
```

Comment: What do you want to do with AC_PREIX_CONFIG_H?

Comment: @ztik,sorry, the macro AC_PREIX_CONFIG_H is wrong,it should be  AC_PREFIX_CONFIG_H.And I want to generate an installable config.h, which is prefixed with PACKAGE-NAME,like libhot_config.h. and the macro names in this config.h will be prefixed with corresponding PACKAGE-NAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typoed the macro: `AC_PREIX_CONFIG_H` does not exist; `AC_PREFIX_CONFIG_H` used to, but it's obsolete, the correct one is [`AX_PREFIX_CONFIG_H`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_prefix_config_h.html).

Also if you want to use this macro you should look at how to use [external macro files](https://autotools.io/autoconf/macros.html) (full disclosure: I wrote that documentation.)

Comment: Thanks, I subsitute the `AX_PREFIX_CONFIG_H` for `AC_PREFIX_CONFIG_H`. The `autoconf` and `autoheader` woks.but when running ./configure,I get  new error,like this:`config.status: error: no prefix for _PREFIX_PKG_CONFIG_H
`,@Diego

Comment: That seems to be because the macro expects you to have either defined `PACKAGE` (which happens if you call `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE`) or pass a second paramter.